# Spring Data JPA: Nested objects design - unidirectional? bidirectional?

Tags: hibernate, rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Let's say I have nested objects like this:

```
Customer

   Project

      Rent

         Fault

(and maybe deeper)
```

Customer contains the user rights I must verify.
Then there is a method to update a fault:

```
void updateFault(long faultId, String content, User user) { .. }
```

Question: How to get from fault to customer?

1. Option: Using backreference to parent: Fault to Rent, Rent to Project, Project to Customer
2. Option: Using backreference from Fault to Customer (and also from Rent to Customer etc)
3. Option: No backreference and walk up by a lot of database queries like

   rent = rentRepository.findByFault(fault);

   project = projectRepository.findByRent(rent);

   customer = customerRepository.findByProject(project);

I read that I should avoid bidirectional reference. But what if I have 20 levels and a lot of data? Then Option #3 is not suitable at all.

I am using Spring Data JPA in a Spring MVC project.

Comment: Option 1 ist perfectly fine. Read more about the benefits of bidirectional relationships. http://in.relation.to/2016/09/28/performance-tuning-and-best-practices/

Comment: What's the reason you map from the more core generic concept to the more concrete one? Usually you'd do it exactly the other way round. Fault is associated to a rent, rent to a project, the project to a customer. This way you can use repository queries on the the more concrete to find items by more generic concepts (i.e. things like FaultRepository.findByCustomer(…) using a manually declare query).

Comment: @OliverGierke Thank you. I have never learned that I should do it the other way round. This is just from OOP point of view (a customer has a list of projects ..). Do you have any deeper information (tutorials) about that? 

I will try it out tomorrow.

Comment: If you model "has a" relationships, you will end up a couple of classes become god classes as they have relationships to everything else in the system. Things like `User`, `Customer` are great candidates for that mistake. I usually try to think of in "belongs to" relationships, that avoids that fallacy. Also, I usually think about `…ToMany` relationships twice as it's easy to run into issues with lazy loading. Obtaining collections is usually more flexible using query methods. No particular books in mind, just personal experience.

Comment: Maybe one more thought — I guess I should've made this an answer :) —: it usually helps to think of what can go standalone in the first place. A `Customer` without a `Project` is probably fine, whereas a `Project` not belonging to a `Customer` is invalid. In a scenario like that, only model the relationship required by the domain (P -> C).

Answer (score 1):

In general there are probably use cases for each of your options, and I'd even like to add two more:

1. No backreference and walk up by a single join
2. change your model so those back references in question become the main references.

Let's look at the properties of the various approaches

1. **Backreferences**: This basically mean bidirectional mapping. While there is nothing wrong in principle, it is hard to get them correct, because basically when manipulationg the references in java you have to keep both directions in sync, which from my experience is very easy to get wrong.
2. **Direct Backreferences**: Once you have those, I guess it is just a question of time until you get references back to Project and Rent as well. Also this creates cyclic dependencies between classes that are otherwise not directly related at all. Together this Leaves you (IMHO) with a tangled mess.
3. **Cascade of database queries** This is just going to be slow. The only scenario where I would do this is, when I have a model that really nicely fits all my other requirements and I need this construct only in very sparse situations, where performance is irrelevant.
4. **Direct Join back**: Compared to the direct Backreferences, it doesn't create the dependency tangle on the java side. You'll have to write custom queries, but thos should be straight forward. Sounds like a reasonable solution to me.
5. **revert the references in your model** (I'm stealing points from @Oliver Gierke here): With your current modelling approach you easily end up with one entity that has a *has* relationship to everything else. If your domain is non trivial this is going to become messy. If you have a 1:N relationship this very often implies that the N side can be zero/empty, so it is really optional. Also you very often only need subsets. Like all the non finished projects, or all the projects that are behind schedule. So in many cases it makes sense to model the reference in the opposite direction. And if you need to navigate the original direction, use a repository for that.